# Python asyncio ensure_future

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm studying Python's `asyncio` library and i'm having a hard time understanding how some Python functions work.
For example:

```
import asyncio
async def coroutine():
    print('Initialize coroutine')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Done !')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
#asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine())
#loop.create_task(coroutine())
loop.run_forever()
```

For example in the code if I make use of ensure_future it automatically starts the execution of my task, so does create_task, but in the case of create task I even understand that it uses the loop used in the loop.create_task method call. My question is because using ensure_future it already starts executing the task, and if it does this because in some case I see codes like this:

```
import asyncio
async def coroutine():
    print('Initialize coroutine')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Done !')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine())
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([task]))
```

Comment: Cannot understand your representation. Could you make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is because using ensure_future it already starts executing the task, and if it does this

Yes, `ensure_future` starts executing the coroutine as soon as the event loop is resumed, even if no one `await`s the returned future.

This feature of `ensure_future` follows from the implementation, but it also makes sense conceptually.

- On the implementation level, it is a consequence of `ensure_future` [internally calling `create_task`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/866c168a5f9330d8a3ae109fa8baab2509f35cc7/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L577) when given a coroutine object. In other words, for coroutines there is no difference between `loop.create_task` and `asyncio.ensure_future`. Otherwise the difference is that `ensure_future` is more general: it takes any [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-awaitable) object, and converts it to a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future). If it receives a coroutine object, `create_task` performs the appropriate conversion and the new [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) (itself a subclass of `Future`) is returned. If the argument to `ensure_future` is already a `Future` or its subclass, it is returned unchanged.
- On the conceptual level, `ensure_future` returns an object that represents the "future" value of a computation, i.e. it encapsulates the result of execution that happens in the background. In case of a corroutine, running in the background means being scheduled with the event loop. Without ensuring the coroutine's execution, returning a `Future` would be misleading because that future would never arrive.